# How can you dynamically change an Excel table column reference?

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have multiple Excel tables storing numeric values.  I am summarizing a rows values like this:

`=+SUM(Query_Current_Year[@[Begin_Balance]:[Balance_Period6]])`

Every month, I need to update each table like this:

`=+SUM(Query_Current_Year[@[Begin_Balance]:[Balance_Period7]])`

Is there a way to store the current column string in a cell like A1 with the value of  "Balance_Period6", then reference cell A1? Each month, I would only need to update one field.

I can think of numerous reasons to need this, so I am certain there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand every detail of the logic, this is the fix.

'''=SUM(INDIRECT("_2360_2860["&A7&"]"))'''

You need to wrap the full table reference in an indirect function.  I was hoping for something more readable but it works.